# Memory leak outgoing messages rabbitmq

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-integration, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I have a Spring Boot application that is using Spring Integration. And I have problem with increasing memory over time. When I run profiler I can see problem in outbound endpoint when it seems like confirmation is not received. When I try debug the handling of confirmation locally everything looks ok. It appears only in k8s environment where a lot of messages are being sent (Maybe that is why local env is without problem). The error seems it appears after upgrade of springboot from version 1.6 to 2.3 (and all dependent dependencies). So that why I think it some missconfiguration but I am not sure where or why.

Versions:

- spring boot: 2.3.3.RELEASE
- spring-rabbitmq: 2.2.10.RELEASE
- spring integration: 5.3.2.RELEASE

Configuration:

```
protected RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate() {
    RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate();
    rabbitTemplate.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(new ContentTypeDelegatingMessageConverter());
    
    rabbitTemplate.setChannelTransacted(true);

    rabbitTemplate.setMandatory(amqpMandatoryFlag);
    return rabbitTemplate;
}

return IntegrationFlows.from(inputFlowChannel)
                .transform(messageRequestsTransformer())
                .transform(new ObjectToStringTransformer())
                .enrichHeaders(headers)
                .log(LoggingHandler.Level.INFO, "amqpOutboundConnectorLogging",
                        "headers.id + ': outboundAMQPPayload=' + payload")
                .handle(Amqp.outboundAdapter(rabbitTemplate())
                        .confirmCorrelationExpression("payload")
                        .returnChannel(returnChannel)
                        .exchangeName(amqpExchangeTarget)
                        .defaultDeliveryMode(messageDeliveryMode)
                        .headersMappedLast(true)
                );

public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
    CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory();
    connectionFactory.setUri(this.amqpBrokerUri);
    connectionFactory.setChannelCacheSize(this.amqpChannelCacheSize);
    connectionFactory.setCacheMode(CacheMode.CHANNEL);
    connectionFactory.setRequestedHeartBeat(60);
    connectionFactory.setPublisherReturns(true);
    return connectionFactory;
}
```

Profiler screen:[image]

If some other configuration is need I will add it.

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: Boot 2.3 is no longer supported; try 2.5.x https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot#support

Comment: I know, but upgrade to 2.5.x is quite difficult because of other dependencies, so it not possible with current timeline.... But I did not find any similar problem related to 2.3.x version....

Comment: If you can provide an [MCRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that exhibits the behavior someone could take a look, at least to see if there is a work around; I doubt there will be a new release for such an old version (unless you have a support contract with VMware). At the very least you should upgrade to the latest versions in those lines, Boot 2.3.12, AMQP 2.2.22, Integration 5.3.10.

Comment: Upgrade to versions Boot 2.3.12, AMQP 2.2.22, Integration 5.3.10 did not help... When I looking into implemetation differences between versions 1.7 and 2.2 of PublisherCallbackChannelImpl I can see that there is no pendingReturns map in the older version - this is only in the new one. So I am thinking about some missing configuration or some wrong settings, because heap does not increase pendingConfirms map but only the pendingReturns map.

Comment: As I said, if you provide an MCRE that exhibits this behavior, I will take a look, even though 2.2.x is out of support. I can't guess how you are using the framework.

Comment: Hello, sorry for delay but I created a MCRE: https://github.com/jvermirovsky/amqp-leak Please check. If you need anything else, just ask. But this is a basic configuration of how it is used (not nice and new but it is a migrated old code). Just change application.properties where is configured url, routing key and exchange name. The exchange was created as direct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the reproducer; there are several issues; the root cause is using transactions with returns.

You can't use publisher confirms with transactions and the confirms/returns are designed to work together; there is nothing to trigger the removal of the pending returns.

Scheduling a call to `template.getUnconfirmed()` would normally help with clearing the pending returns, but it doesn't work.

There are several contributing factors as to why the memory is leaked, not least of which is the channel doesn't increment the `nextPublishSeqNo` so the `pendingConfirms` indexing is broken; the `pendingConfirms` map is used to trigger the cleanup so we still leave `pendingReturns` around.

The workaround (for now) is to use publisher confirms instead of transactions (or disable returns), but I will see if I can come up with a workaround while using transactions.

```
connectionFactory.setPublisherConfirmType(ConfirmType.CORRELATED);
```

**EDIT**

I found the issue; the problem is you are telling the adapter to create correlation data for each request...

```
.confirmCorrelationExpression("payload")
```

...this is an instruction to the template to maintain the pending confirms/returns maps, which are never cleared out because confirms cannot be enabled with transactions.

Remove this and the adapter won't configure the template for confirms.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/issues/1439

Comment: I found what's wrong with your configuration; see the edit.

Comment: Thank you very much for explanation and pointing the issue. Now it works correctly. Thank you once more.