# spring-rabbitmq find a memory leak, but i don't know the reason, can someone help me

Tags: java, spring, memory-leaks, jvm, spring-rabbit

my application use rabbit mq, the versions are below

> spring-amqp : 2.2.17.RELEASE
> spring-rabbit : 2.2.17.RELEASE
> spring-boot: 2.3.11.RELEASE

```
    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "firstConnectionFactory")
    public ConnectionFactory firstConnectionFactory() {
        CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.setHost(host);
        connectionFactory.setPort(port);
        connectionFactory.setUsername(username);
        connectionFactory.setPassword(password);
        connectionFactory.setPublisherConfirms(true); 
        return connectionFactory;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "firstRabbitTemplate")
    @Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    public RabbitTemplate firstRabbitTemplate() {
        return new RabbitTemplate(firstConnectionFactory());
    }

    //send a message
    private void prepareForString(String exchange, String queueName, JSONObject message) {
        try {
            RabbitTemplate template = rabbitConfig.firstRabbitTemplate();
            template.convertAndSend(exchange, queueName, JSON.toJSONStringWithDateFormat(message,   DateUtils.YYYYMMDDHHMMSS, SerializerFeature.WriteMapNullValue));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

after the application run about 1 year, i find the application run very slow, dump the heap, then i see

[heap show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9prVl.png)

> One instance of "org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.PublisherCallbackChannelImpl" loaded by "org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader @ 0x6c001a6d0" occupies 405.62 MB (12.57%) bytes. The memory is accumulated in one instance of "org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.PublisherCallbackChannelImpl" loaded by "org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader @ 0x6c001a6d0".
> Keywords
> org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.PublisherCallbackChannelImpl
> org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader @ 0x6c001a6d0

it looks like the PublisherCallbackChannelImpl.java has a listeners, and the listeners is very huge. the listeners is defined below

```
//PublisherCallbackChannelImpl.java line 59
private final ConcurrentMap<String, PublisherCallbackChannel.Listener> listeners = new ConcurrentHashMap();
```

the below is the code of put elements in map

```
    //PublisherCallbackChannelImpl.java line 549
    public void addListener(PublisherCallbackChannel.Listener listener) {
        Assert.notNull(listener, "Listener cannot be null");
        if (this.listeners.size() == 0) {
            this.delegate.addConfirmListener(this);
            this.delegate.addReturnListener(this);
        }
        //the key code, below 'listener' is RabbitTemplate object
        if (this.listeners.putIfAbsent(listener.getUUID(), listener) == null) {
            this.pendingConfirms.put(listener, new ConcurrentSkipListMap());
            if (this.logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                this.logger.debug("Added listener " + listener);
            }
        }

    }
```

i want know why this happens, and where is the listeners.remove(XXX), or it has no listeners.remove()?

i try look for the PublisherCallbackChannelImpl.java , but there is no listeners.remove() anywhere

so i what know, is this the reason of memory leak?

Comment: Please use text instead of images. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question for more details on the reason. It is ok for the heap screen though you should have highlighted the actual line that you wanted us to see. Versions of packages are not visual information and should be provided textually.

Comment: How are you certain that that retained memory is the cause of the slowness? What is the used heap and max heap over time? What is the CPU use over time? Have you analyzed thread dumps? You haven't shown any relationship between that line in the heap dump and the slowness issue. Be sure that this is not an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Have you look at the release notes of every Spring library and AMQP libraries to see if memory leaks are fixed? Are there other uses of AMQP in your application that you didn't share? Why you didn't share the full class?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Memory leak outgoing messages rabbitmq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71482356/memory-leak-outgoing-messages-rabbitmq)

Comment: Why is your `RabbitTemplate` is a ` @Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)`? Why default `singleton` is not enough for you?

Comment: Would be great if you can share a minimal project with us to be able to reproduce the problem on our side.

Comment: thank you very much,i will add more information @aled

Comment: Edit the question to add additional information. Answers should be posted as answers not comments.

Comment: thank you very much @aled, I had post the answer and changed problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the reason of leak is here, SCOPE_PROTOTYPE and RabbitTemplate template = rabbitConfig.firstRabbitTemplate(); too many rabbitTemplate objects, and these rabbit template is in the map, and not gc by jvm, because the channel is not close, the map is related to the channel. so the map not gc by jvm. i think the designer of spring-rabbit not consider too many values in that map. the designer might think only one or serval rabbitTemplate objects, so the map will not too big. but when rabbitTemplate use SCOPE_PROTOTYPE or new every time, that will generate too many rabbitTemplate in the map, that cause the memory leak.
I had changed to the below code.

```
//remove the @Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
//default singleton
@Primary
@Bean(name = "firstRabbitTemplate")
public RabbitTemplate firstRabbitTemplate() {
    return new RabbitTemplate(firstConnectionFactory());
}

//I use spring autowired to import RabbitTemplate Object 
@Autowired
RabbitTemplate firstRabbitTemplate;

/**
 * send message;
 */
private void prepareForString(String exchange, String queueName, JSONObject message) {
    try {
       //use just one firstRabbitTemplate obejct
       firstRabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(exchange, queueName, JSON.toJSONStringWithDateFormat(message,
                    DateUtils.YYYYMMDDHHMMSS, SerializerFeature.WriteMapNullValue));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        log.error(ex.getMessage());
    }

}
```